Shore pass when connecting flight via HND on the same day
I have a connecting flight from New Delhi to Seattle via Haneda airport. My flight lands at HND on Oct 24th 05:55 and takes off on Oct 24th 21:15 to Seattle. I have secured my visa for US.
I would like to know if there is any scope of me being allowed to take part in leisurely activities such as visiting tourist places within the 15 hour layover. I am aware of the on-arrival shore pass but since I have a connecting flight on the same day would I still be given the shore pass?
Would a transit visa help me travel outside the airport if I am able to secure that before my departure to HND?
Edit: I hold an Indian normal passport

I am skipping transit visa, I would let the forum know how it would be

The exact conditions of the Shore Pass are surprisingly poorly documented, but as far as I'm aware there is no minimum stay/overnight requirement to obtain one.  So yes, you are eligible. You will need your airline's support to get the Shore Pass though, so let them know at check-in.
If you don't want to take your chances, getting a transit visa will guarantee that you can leave the airport, but I'm not sure it's worth the hassle.

My experience was very positive. As soon as I landed the airport security and staff was well aware of the shore pass. I had no troubles getting a shore pass, I was out of the airport within 45 mins of landing. As long as you have the necessary documents to enter your terminal country you should be fine.

Thanks for coming back to report how it went!
